# Ocaml probleme with square number

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

I have a problem with a certain exercise that said integer_square_root that calculates the integer square root of a positive integer `n`, that is the largest integer `r` such that `r * r <= n`. Hint: you may use floating point arithmetic, but don't forget that you have to convert explicitly between float and int.

I tried to write my code and I thought it was correct but from the description of the exercise that is not the solution:

```
let integer_square_root n = n*n;
```

Comment: Please also post your attempt

Comment: I think `let integer_square_root n = n*n;` is the attempt, which calculates the square of n, not the square root.

Comment: You'll probably want to implement [the babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method), but I find it hard to believe that you're supposed to figure that one out on your own.

Comment: There are several ways to solve this problem. Given the hint, maybe you are allowed to use the [sqrt](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALsqrt) function on floating-point numbers. Another (inefficient) idea is to iterate upwards from 0 to find which integer when squared is less than the target.

Comment: Maybe you should ask your teacher for advice...

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for the `square root`, and there you are trying n^2 with `n * n`.
To calculate the square root you can use the function `sqrt` available in OCaml Pervasives.